# Focus selector in Sass

Tags: css, input, sass, focus, selector

I focus in the input field and need to change the color of an icon and border-bottom of that class. How do I do it in Sass? I have already tried:

```
input
 + .input-group-addon // this is icon class
   &:focus
    border-bottom: solid 2px #004eff
```

However it does nothing. Could you please help me? This is what HTML looks like.

```
<div class="form-group" class="col-md-offset-1 col-xl-offset-1  focus-icon">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon man-icon"></div>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Логин"  required>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this.
**EDIT:** I had missed a . when i pasted the answer.

```
.input-group
  input
    &:focus
      & + .input-group-addon
        border-bottom: solid 2px #004eff
```

Here you can see the SASS generated CSS in action.
**NOTE:** The position in the DOM for "the icon" has been moved.

```css
.input-group input:focus+.input-group-addon {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #004eff;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" class="col-md-offset-1 col-xl-offset-1  focus-icon">
  <div class="input-group">

    <input type="email" placeholder="Логин" required>
    <div class="input-group-addon man-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then I'd like to know what the indeded CSS should look like.
if you dont want the `input + .input-group-addon` but instead want `input.input-group-addon`, you need to remove the `+` and a space, so that it becomes `&.input-group-addon`

Comment: Guess I'm not good at describing what I want. I have an input field and icon next to it. When I focus on input it is underlined with blue, however the icon is still underlined with grey, while I want it to be blue as well. Does that make sense?

Comment: I changed it, tried it. Sorry for the sloppy first answer. Focused on the syntax, not the intended result (screaming toddlers in the background tend to make me less focused) :)

Comment: It's okay. You were trying to help :)

Comment: Kids are sleeping. Answer is checked and dubble checked. :) Included the SASS-generated CSS with a "Run code snippet".